# PhP download to root folder

Tags: php, download, root

If I have a php file on my root folder on my website, is there a way to go to a download line with that file and download the file to the directory where the php is rather than to the computer>

Comment: Not without FTP.  The PHP file will execute if you try and get it through the browser.  If you could do that, it would be a pretty serious security hole!

Comment: you can actully set the file type to txt via .htaccess and then do it, but probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cale_b said, no, not without FTP. The PHP file will execute if you try and get it through the browser. Why do you want to do that anyway?